# Chromium quickly opens/closes an extra tab when started

Tags: chromium, browser

I have noticed on my chromium that when I launch it for the first time in a session it opens my home page (fine), but it also very quickly opens and closes one tab multiple times.
Also on the chromium logo on the dash I see quickly appearing the downloading bar.
If I close the browser and reopen it in the same session it doesn't happen.
I'm scared it might be something malicious. 
Any ideas on what it could be at all?

(Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by extensions. Maybe some of them are perfroming some actions that they think they need to do on browser start (check for updates for example)